# Excel 2013: Change text in cell based on date in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have the the following spreadsheet: http://postimg.org/image/nti4akie5/
My formula in Columns A to E is the following:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(Query1_2[@Branch],Master!A:J,10,FALSE)),"Branch Not Open",VLOOKUP(Query1_2[@Branch],Master!A:J,10,FALSE))
```

I would like to do the following in Column A:
If the date in Column C is greater than today, then Column A must also say "Branch Not Open".
I have tried the following:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(Query1_2[@Branch],Master!A:J,10,FALSE)),"Branch Not Open",VLOOKUP(Query1_2[@Branch],Master!A:J,10,FALSE)),IF(C:C<=TODAY,"Branch Not Open, IF(AND(C:C=>TODAY,VLOOKUP(Query1_2[@Branch],Master!A:I,9,FALSE)))
```

But Excel does not like the formula at all. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the formula you are using is needlessly complicated. Try this:

**=IF(*col C date*>TODAY(),"Branch Not Open",*value if false*)**

The IF function works like this IF(logical test,value if true, value if false). In my formula, the logical test is whether or not the date value in column C is greater than the current day.

The TODAY function will update itself automatically every time the workbook is opened, based on the system clock of the computer.

[image]

Comment: =IF(C:C>TODAY(),"Branch Not Open",VLOOKUP(Query1_2[@Branch],Master!A:J,10,FALSE))    --- 100% !